# How do i prevent my React component from rendering unnecessarily?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I have a react app. On this app I am rendering 10 tables. When a user makes a change to a table I only want that one table to re-render, not all 10.

To accomplish this task I have used `React.useMemo()` with a comparer function. Here it is:

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
  const { categoryTotal: ctPrev, ...prev } = prevProps;
  const { categoryTotal: ctNext, ...next } = nextProps;

  if (
    !ctPrev.totalPrice.eq(ctNext.totalPrice) &&
    !ctPrev.totalWeight.eq(ctNext.totalWeight) &&
    !ctPrev.totalWorn.eq(ctNext.totalWorn) &&
    !ctPrev.totalConsumable.eq(ctNext.totalConsumable)
  ) {
    console.log('totals did change')
    return false;
  }

  for (var key in next) {
    if (next[key] !== prev[key]) {
      console.log('not equal', key);
      return false;
    }
  }

  console.log('props did not change')
  return true;
}

export default React.memo(CategoryTable, areEqual);
```

I have verified that true is being returned for every table except the one that changes. So only that one table should re-render and not all 10 right? Wrong. Here is my flamegraph:
[image]

The name of my table component is CategoryTable. As you can see, the CategoryTable (memo) is grayed out but the subsequent CategoryTable is green and renders as does all of its children. I have confirmed that every category table is rendering by putting a console.log in the CategoryTable component.

How do I actually stop this component from re-rendering? Also does react.memo stop all components below in the tree from rendering or just the wrapped component?

Comment: you can try and use your  `areEqual` function in the `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle funtion. If nothing has changed, just return false.

Answer (score 0):

React.memo return cach if the value didnt change its really usefull but in your case you can try pureComponent ,it prevent to render the children components if their props dont change

Comment: PureComponent does the same thing as memo. The only difference is PureComponent is for class components and memo if for functional components.